# Converting decimal to hex and make sure they are numbers

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

I am trying to create an error catch while entering an odometer reading.  It seems that my ODO value isn't being converted to HEX and will only allow ODO values between 30 and 39 (instead of the HEX values 30 to 39 which are decimal numbers 0-9).

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function checkFormStartShift()
{
    var vODOstart = document.startshift.odostart.value;
    vConvertHex = vODOstart.toString(16);
    var vError = "no";
    
    for (var i = 0; i < vConvertHex.length; i=i+2) 
    {
        let result = vConvertHex.substr(i, 2);
        if (result < 30 || result > 39)
        {
            alert("Starting KMs should be numbers only");
            vError = "yes";
            return false;
        }
    }
            
    if (vODOstart < 0 && vError == "no")
    {   
        return true;
    }
               
    else if (vODOstart <= 0)
    {
        alert("Starting ODO cannot be 0 or negative.  Please correct.");
        return false;
    }   
    
}
</script>
```

Comment: I figured out how to accomplish this in PHP, but that happens on the next page, then the user has to go back.  I want to have the error catch before the user is allowed to proceed.

Comment: Unclear what you’re trying to do with the if .  Result is a string of 2 hex digits from 00 to FF presumably.  Under what circumstances should the if condition trigger?

Comment: The for loop should look at each set of hex values.  The if should compare the hex value and if it is outside the values 30 to 39 (decimal values for 0 through 9) then show the alert and make my error flag true.

Comment: So if the two digit part you are checking is <= `2F` or  >= `3A` it should show the message?

Answer (score 0):

#### Debugging tips:

1. Make sure your input is a number, and not already a string
2. You are comparing with 30 and 39, rather than with 48 and 48+9. You are thinking of the hex values "30" and "39", but have written the decimal values.
3. Instrument your code a bit more to get further information:

```
function checkFormStartShift()
{
    var vODOstart = document.startshift.odostart.value;

    console.log("vODOstart:",vODOstart)
    console.log("typeof vODOstart:",typeof vODOstart)

    vConvertHex = vODOstart.toString(16);

    console.log("vConvertHex:",vConvertHex)
    
    var vError = "no";
    
    for (var i = 0; i < vConvertHex.length; i=i+2) 
    {
        let result = vConvertHex.substr(i, 2);
        if (result < 48 || result > 48+9)
        {
            alert("Starting KMs should be numbers only");
            vError = "yes";
            return false;
        }
    }
            
    if (vODOstart < 0 && vError == "no")
    {   
        return true;
    }
               
    else if (vODOstart <= 0)
    {
        alert("Starting ODO cannot be 0 or negative.  Please correct.");
        return false;
    }   
    
}
```

#### Suggested improvements

- Do not try to convert to Hex: you are not going to do anything with the hex characters.
- Instead convert the vODOstart into an integer.
- You seem to be doing this conversion in order to find unacceptable characters and reject the input. Instead you could overwrite the document.startshift.odostart.value with a "cleaned" version.

```
function checkFormStartShift()
{
    var vODOstart = document.startshift.odostart.value;
    vConvertNumber = Math.int(vODOstart);

    if (vODOstart > 0)
    {   
        document.startshift.odostart.value = vConvertNumber;
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {
        alert("Starting ODO cannot be 0 or negative.  Please correct.");
        return false;
    }   

}
```